# Grunt "copy" noProcess option is not working?

Tags: gruntjs, copy

It's look like noProcess option is ignored in my init settings for "copy" plugin. 
Any one knows why this is happening ? I dont get any errors but the source folder/files (src/source/**) that it suppose to be ignored is copied over to destiantion folder.

Those are my settings in the init function:

```
        copy: {
            options: {
                noProcess: ["!src/source/**"]
            },
            prod: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true, 
                        src: ['src/**'], 
                        dest: 'build/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Definition

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

Call:

```
grunt.registerTask("prod", ["concat", "uglify", "htmlmin", "imagemin", "copy"]);
```

Anyone see the problem or whats more important a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this setting does the job. But still, I do not understand how the noProcess option should be used to work as expected.

```
        copy: {
            prod: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true, 
                        src: ['src/**', '!src/source/**/*', '!src/source'], 
                        dest: 'build/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```